# Are "Schmankerln" always Bavarian?

Tags: meaning, bavarian

Is a "Schmankerl" a regional specialty, or does it refer to delicatesses anywhere although the word is used in Bavaria and Austria?

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmankerl) and [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schmankerl) give the meanings "besonderer Leckerbissen" and "Leckerbissen, Spezialität" respectively, indicating the latter. Would a bavarian call borscht a Russian "Schmankerl"?

Answer (score 8):

Meanwhile, it does refer to delicacies anywhere. "Schmankerln" can be used in different figurative senses:

- to denote other than austrian / tyrolean / bavarian / franconian gastronomic delicacies;
- to denote other than gastronomic delicacies, for example musical pieces in a concert or special features of an object ([Die Zeit about a special edition of the "Mini"](http://www.zeit.de/auto/2011-04/mini-goodwood): "Schmankerln wie Xenonscheinwerfern oder Karbon-Außenspiegeln");
- to denote "non-delicacies", for example in an ironic way to describe certain "features" in a political context: again ["Die Zeit" about political plans regarding a educational reform](http://www.zeit.de/2010/32/C-NRW): "...Schmankerln wie der Abschaffung der Kopfnoten, der Stärkung der Elternrechte oder dem Versprechen, das Einschulungsalter konstant zu halten...".

Regarding "musikalische Schmankerln": Gogle has ~310,000 hits for that phrase. Some examples for non-austrian / -bavarian gastronomic "Schmankerln":

- an [article](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/alhambra-im-deutschen-theater-jamn-jamn-1.1083729) from the "Süddeutsche Zeitung" (Munich), describing a restaurant: "... stärkt man sich [in diesem Restaurant] mit spanischen und marrokanischen Schmankerln."
- the "Süddeutsche" again: "[Schmankerln made in Asia](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/tenmaya-schmankerln-made-in-asia-1.390045)".
- an [vietnamese restaurant](http://www.van-long.de/) in Berlin advertising its "Schmankerln";
- a [recipe](http://www.gekonntgekocht.de/rezepte/26/kleine_gerichte/54/fischgerichte/1685/garnelen_suess/) that doesn' sound austrian / bavarian to me.
- an [article from the weekly "Die Zeit"](http://www.zeit.de/2004/07/Siebeck_2fWeinlese_25) mentioning "französische Schmankerln".

However, "Schmankerln" is still predominantly used to denote austrian / bavarian dishes.

Comment: Not sure about Bavarian, but in Austrian we also use the word to denote "goodies" when used to make a deal more attractive - so it's not exclusively about food even though food is the origin.